# Redis clients broadcast problems (in the context of Socket.IO)

Tags: redis, socket.io, scalability, publish-subscribe, disconnect

So I've read some articles about scaling Socket.IO. For various reasons I don't want to use built-in Socket.IO scaling mechanism (mostly it seems to be inefficient, since it publishes a lot more stuff to Redis then required from my point of view).

So I've came up with this simple idea:

Each Socket.IO server creates Redis pub/sub/store clients, connects to Redis and subscribes to a channel. Now, when I want to broadcast data I just publish it to Redis and all other Socket.IO servers get it and push it to users.

There is a problem, though (which I think is also a problem for Socket.IO built-in mechanism). Let's say I want to know the number of all connected users. There are at least two ways of doing that:

1. Server A publishes `give_me_clients` to Redis. Then each Socket.IO server counts connections and publishes `number_of_clients`. Server A grabs this data, combines it and sends it to the client.
2. Each server updates `number_of_clients_for::ID_HERE` in Redis whenever user connects/disconnects to the server. Then Server A just fetches data and combines it. Might be more efficient.

There are problems with these solutions though:

1. Server A is not aware of other servers. Therefore he does not know when he should stop listening to `number_of_clients`. One could fix it with making Server A aware of other servers: whenever a server connects to Redis he publishes `new_server` (Server A grabs the data and stores it in memory). But what to do, when Redis - Socket.IO connection breaks? Is there a way for Redis to notify clients that one of the client disconnected?
2. Actually the same as above. When a Socket.IO server crashes how to clear `number_of_clients` data?

So the real question is: can Redis notify (publish to chanel) clients that the connection with one of them has just ended??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of testing it seems, that Redis does not have such functionality. Also I've found out, that scaling Socket.IO is really a pain.

So I've switched from Socket.IO to WS (see [this link](https://github.com/einaros/ws)). It is low level (but perfect for my use) and it only supports WebSockets (in all major versions). But then again I only want to support WebSockets and FlashSocket (which I have to imlement manually, but that's fine).

The advantage is that I can easily create cluster with such servers. HAProxy works with such servers almost out of the box (some minor tuning). Servers can easily communicate on a local net (with UDP or central TCP server if the cluster is big).

The disadvantage is that one have to manually implement some cool features like heartbeats, broadcasting, rooms, etc. Also you want have long-polling fallback, but that's fine in my  case. Scaling is still more important, imho.

Comment: I've switched to ws as well, and I basically run a process.on exit and loop through `wss.clients` and delete all `user:ids` in my redis storage (if a server fails). One simple issue I'm having is private messaging. If I had 2 ws servers on ports 9300 and 9301, and a user from 9301 wants to send a message to a user that's in 9300 (or could be any other server/port), I'm not sure how to let that other user know. Do I just publish the private message request to the redis server and figure out what wss server that user is on to send them a message?

Comment: @NiCkNewman I think that for each user you should keep info about on which server that user is (in one shared place like Redis). Then you just retrieve that info and you send a message directly to the target server. But the most efficient way to do it is by user being aware on which server his friend is and sending the message directly to that server.

Comment: Of course all of that depends on the context. For example you might want to keep chat history (e.g. Facebook) and then it all becomes more complicated. I don't have much experience with chat servers so I don't want to lead you in wrong direction. :(

Comment: Hmm, I see. So for each ws server (instance) keep a track/list of all connected clients? Or do you mean store the port number and server information as a property for every redis user value? Or both? :)

Comment: @NiCkNewman I'm sure that both will be handy. :) But I've meant to keep server info as a property of every Redis user. That way it will be fastest to find the desired server.

Comment: @freskish I found something [here](https://gist.github.com/bricecarpentier/5599799) that might work as well with just the ID. I'll try it out though, not sure if I feel comfortable of every server instance knowing that some random user sent a message... but I guess that's the price to pay of using redis and scaling :)  Thank you for your help! ~